# How to upload Multiple Images using Array List in android

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, retrofit2

I try many solutions but no once work for me.

I'm receiving images data in this way:

```
ArrayList<String> filePaths = data.getStringArrayListExtra(Pix.IMAGE_RESULTS);
```

and uploading images using multipart

```
MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();
    Call<Status_Response> call = taskMetServer.uploadMultiplePics(requestBody.parts());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Status_Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Status_Response> call, Response<Status_Response> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()){

                Status_Response status_response = response.body();

                assert status_response != null;
                String msg = status_response.getStatus();

                Log.d("myMessage", "\n\nStatus: "+msg);

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Success " + response.message()+response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Status_Response> call, Throwable t) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

my interface is:

```
@POST("test/store")
Call<Status_Response> uploadMultiplePics(
        @Body List<MultipartBody.Part> images
);
```

but still receiving null in response instead of true of false:

```
2021-03-20 17:36:38.076 10582-10582/com.example.ourproductapp D/myMessage: [/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20210320-WA0082.jpeg]

2021-03-20 17:36:38.732 10582-10582/com.example.ourproductapp D/myMessage: Status: null
```

- 

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your backend service, your server is getting file or not.
or you can use https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service library